# When to delete file in website that provide stream to a client?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I create a file on the web server where I store my data streamed to the client. It could be big file more than 500MB or even much bigger.
So I am wondering when to delete the file or how to know that the files is not used for streaming anymore and to delete it.

Any suggestions or pattern for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Each time someone begins a streaming request, could you increment an application-level counter? When done streaming, then decrement it? When the counter hits 0 (zero) it will safe to delete.